# On updating @testing-library/jest-dom version from 4.0.0 to 4.2.0 react test case is failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

On updating @testing-library/jest-dom version from 4.0.0 to 4.2.0 react test cases which are used to check styles by using toHaveStyles are failing.
Test using react-testing-library:

```
test('renders component', () => {
const { getByTestId } = render(<Temp labels={labels} justify="end" />);
expect(getByTestId('temp')).toHaveStyle('justifyContent: end');
```

});

the above test is failing and it's throwing an error as follows:

```
 ● Temp › renders component

expect(element).toHaveStyle()

- Expected

- justifyContent: end;
+ 

  24 |   test('renders component', () => {
  25 |     const { getByTestId } = render(<Temp labels={labels} justify="end" />);
> 26 |     expect(getByTestId('temp')).toHaveStyle('justifyContent: end');
     |                                   ^
  27 |   });
  28 | });
  29 | 

  at Object.toHaveStyle (src/components/Temp/tests/Temp.test.js:26:35)
```

Does anyone know the fix to this issue?

Comment: Hint: you are matching style `justifyContent` with prop `justify` which dont match.

Comment: I handled that in Temp component 
I gave styles based on justify prop ( styles:{ justifyContent: props => (props.justify ? props.justify : 'start')})
That is not the reason for failing test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toHaveStyle` works with the *rendered* style, so your test needs to be:

```
expect(getByTestId('temp')).toHaveStyle('justify-content: end')
```